# On button Isenabled =false ,I can't see the button background image?

Tags: windows, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I added an image to the background of button now i set the property Isenabled =false of button .Now the thing is I can't see the button background image. I can see the content but not the background. How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to override the template for the disabled state to see this.